# Turing Machine - Generate number sequences

Tags: numbers, sequence, turing-machines

http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html

How would I create a looping number sequence such as:

01011011101111011111...

So basically adding a zero, then adding 1, then a zero, then 1 on top of the previous number of ones.

Answer (score 1):

Write `01` on the tape. Move one space to the right. If you're looking at a zero, scan back to the left until you see a zero. Move one space to the right. If you're looking at a one, replace it with a two and move to the right until you see a zero; then keep moving right until you another zero. Replace this zero with one. Then, move back until you see a two. Replace the two with a one. Move one to the right; if you're looking at a one, repeat the process of replacing with two and back again. Eventually, you'll exhaust the previous supply of 1s, so you're looking at a zero when you move one to the right. In that case, move right to the next zero, and replace it with one. Loop on this entire process (minus the "write `01` part) to get longer strings of ones.

The intuition behind this is straightforward. If you move to the right and see a zero, move two zeroes to the left, copy all the one's between the last and second-to-last zero after the zero you found, and then add one more one. The two is used as a way to keep track of your position in the string of ones you're copying. The basic idea is sound, but you should try to write out states and transitions for this to make it rigorous.

Example:

```
>
^
>0
 ^
>01
  ^
>010
   ^
>010
 ^
>010
  ^
>020
   ^
>0200
    ^
>0201
   ^
>0201
  ^
>0101
   ^
>0101
    ^
>01010
     ^
>010110
      ^
```